# Replace "spaces" of three textbox values with "+" and seperate with comma

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I have three text boxes that may have various words in each text box.

For example:

**Textbox1**:

Hello my name is

**Textbox2**:

MONZTAAA

**Textbox3**:

And yours

**Result should be**:

Hello+my+name+is,MONZTAAA,and+yours

I have tried the following procedures but dont seem to get it to work:

Try 1:

```
str.replace(/\n/g, '+');
```

Try 2:

```
str.repace(' ', '+');
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I just figured out the answer but not really sure the difference:

This is what I tried before:

```
str.replace(/\n/g, '+');
```

And this is what I have done now:

```
str.replace(/\s/g, '+');
```

The "n" is an "s". Im not sure what this change means so any comment adding info would be great!

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is a good start. It says: `\s stands for "whitespace character". Again, which characters this actually includes, depends on the regex flavor. In all flavors discussed in this tutorial, it includes [ \t\r\n\f]. That is: \s matches a space, a tab, a line break, or a form feed. (...) In flavors that support Unicode, \s normally includes all characters from the Unicode "separator" category. (...) JavaScript does match all Unicode whitespace with \s.`